# .htaccess -- hide dir name in url while keeping folder structure

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a site with files contained in a /pages/ dir.
I'm trying to hide the /pages/ directory from URLs but still have them in the directory, so basically I am trying to achieve this:

> www.example.com/sub/

should load:

> www.example.com/pages/sub/

or

> www.example.com/sub/file.php

should load:

> www.example.com/pages/sub/file.php

-- the aim here is to remove /pages/ from all urls

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/$1 [QSA,L]
```

If file or directory doesn't exist, then try in pages folder.

QSA adds url parameters if any (like ?param1=val1&param2=val2)

Answer (score 1):

Apache Re-write: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Learn it.

Live it.

Hate it?

edit: its a first in first evaluated, last in last evaluated process, so be considerate when specifying rules, as even if one is established correctly, a broader, more general one which also meets the same pattern (depending on wildcards) has the chance to usurp the prior ( think CSS declaration squashing, if you're familiar with that )

Comment: thanks for the url, would look through it and keep trying.

Comment: the simple answer is `RewriteEngine  on` NEWLINE->
`RewriteRule    "^/pages/$"  "/" `

but Rewrite is deceptively "easy" and can cause serious headaches if not fully understood

Comment: @BrandtSolovij that should be in your actual answer, as it is it's basically a "rtfm"-comment at best.

Comment: @ccKep apache rewrites are arguably the gateway drug to full on grok. If the asker made an attempt and posted what they tried - id have capitulated the way you suggest i shoukd have. They didnt so i didnt. Its a valuable question so i didnt flag for repition